# Can one action result leads to two different jsp pages in struts2?

Tags: struts2, action

My question is:
    I have one pop up window to validate some content, and i use action class to do the validation(javascript not allowed). If the content is valid, i need to close this pop up window, and update the content in the main page.
    My idea is in my struts.xml, i mapped 
    `<result name="add" type ="redirectAction"> mainpage.jsp</result>`

is it possible to add
    `<result name="add" > popupCurrentPage.jsp</result>`

to let the same action result leads to two diffent pages at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers may receive a single response for any request.

Doing multiple things on the client side based on a response requires JavaScript *somewhere*.

Answer (score 0):

Use it's possible to add the tag in main page.

`<s:include value="popupCurrentPage.jsp"/>`

but when you are redirecting you will miss the valuestack data, so use messageStore interceptor.